# How do I get largest 20 files across all directories in unix?

Tags: unix, filesize

I want to get the largest 20 files in my unix server across all the directories

I tried to first get all the files across all the directories and then using the pipeline, get the size of each, sorting them and finally getting the top 20 files.

I tried using **find / -type f | du -h | sort -n | head -20**.

But this is not working. The **du** just prints the filesize of current dir.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
find . -type f -exec du -a {} + | sort -n -r | head -20
```